# JavaScript Editor Plugin for Eclipse Mars

Tags: javascript, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-mars

I am trying to find the `JavaScript Development Tools (JSDT)` for the latest `eclipse mars` version.

It seems to me it is not available yet.

Any recommendations what I can use instead to support javascript in eclipse?

I appreciate your answer!

Comment: Eclipse Mars is still in development and the final release will not be until next June. You would be better using the current release - Eclipse Luna.

Comment: @greg-449 Thx for your answer! I downloaded now eclipse luna and tried to find the plugin. Any plugin site you can point me to download it? I appreciate your answer!

Comment: The JavaScript Development Tools are in the main Luna repository - use Install New Software and Work with 'Luna -  http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna'. Note that some of the Luna downloads already include this.

Comment: @greg-449 Thx for your answer! I had a look in each section, but do not find it. Any recommendations what it is named in luna?

Comment: It is called JavaScript Development Tools in the Programming Languages section (also in the Web section). If it was included in your original download it will be hidden unless you deselect 'Hide items that are already installed'.